# How do I add and remove Polygons on Google Maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I'm trying to show and remove polygons onto a Google Map, using v3 of the API. In my JavaScript, I've already got an MVCArray of some custom Lat-Longs.

I'm trying to figure out how to add these polygons and then, based upon some other JavaScript event or user action, such as a click on a polygon (that has been rendered), that polygon will be removed.

Are any code examples available? I'm struggling to find some; most of them usually go to some v2 code.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the API docs, there are a couple of simple examples of [adding a polygon to a map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polygons). Here's the initialize() function from the simple [Bermuda Triangle](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple.html) example with the addition of adding an event listener to remove the polygon when clicked.

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var bermudaTriangle;

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);

  var triangleCoords = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
      new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
      new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
      new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
  ];

  // Construct the polygon
  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

  // add an event listener
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', function() {
      this.setMap(null);
  });

}
```

Comment: AHH! so the trick was to make sure the google.maps.Polygon _instance_ is global .. so u can then reference the same instance to remove it .. instead of trying to find the instance on the map, etc. Gotcha :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer applies to javascript, but definitely applies to java.

If you have a reference to the polygon object you want to remove, then simply call the remove() method of that polygon. Refer to the documentation linked below.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html#remove()

Comment: `polygon.remove()` is only in the Java Android API. In JS use `polygon.setMap(null)`